# To get value using uri segment

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri

Here, we are using uri segment for getting the value from the url.

```
http://localhost/project/ABC/activity/wise_activity
```

Here, if I want `wise_activity`, I can user

```
$this->uri->segment(2).
```

But If I want to get `7` in below url, how can I get?

```
http://localhost/project/ABC/activity/wise_activity?id=7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get 7 by using get method in Active record as

```
 $id=$this->input->get("id");
 echo $id;
```

Read **[Input Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html?highlight=form%20input#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data)**

Comment: Good catch my friend